# Why does my char* copier return different things?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, c-strings, garbage

Writing a simple string copier and testing it in the main() fucntion. What's odd is that sometimes the program returns

"HelloHello"

like it should, but maybe every third time I run it, the program prints out:

"Hello!Hello!▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▒"UòB╚"

Why is the tail of garbage data only sometimes being added to the end of my second string?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int strlength(const char* c)
{
    int size = 0;
    while (*c) {
        ++c;
        ++size;
    }
    return size;
}

char* mystrdup(const char* c)
{
    int size = strlength(c);
    char* result = new char;
    copy(c, c + size, result);
    return result;      
}

void print_array(const char* c)
{
    int size = strlength(c);
    while (*c) {
        cout << *c;
        ++c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "Hello!";
    char* res = mystrdup(test);
    print_array(test);
    print_array(res);
}
```

Comment: Probably you forget to add a \0. Quit all this stuff please and use STL. If this code is the result of your teaching class, quit it *right now*.

Comment: Two words:  **Null termination**.  Second `char* result = new char;` -- only one character?

Comment: *Writing a simple string copier and testing it in the main() fucntion.* -- Try this in a non-trivial program, and you will see that maintaining and using anything looking like this is not so simple.  If you want to increase your skills, write a real string *class*, not these one-off string manipulation routines.

Comment: It's amazing how many programming courses completely neglect the hard part of programming: Making sure that the program still works 25 years later.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with forcing students to use c-strings. It helps them to understand the properties of contiguous memory, as well as experiencing what true suffering feels like. PoliSci can't teach those kinds of life lessons!

Comment: @alteredinstance useful lessons indeed, but they should be taught in a C programming class. Teaching C in C++ classes has left with world with a glut of young programmers who think they know C++ and don't.

Comment: @alteredinstance You should begin with simple ways to solve problems and later you can teach advanced topics like dynamic memory. But don't teach beginners advanced topics.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I started with std::strings - I agree OP should be able to use them first. The real lessons in C I learned were from writing kernels for my OS class. Although if I didn't understand c-strings before that I probably would have had a tough time. C strings should definitely be saved for the intermediate courses and above, certainly.

Comment: In case anyone is familiar with the book, this question is asked while trying to solve Exercize 1 of Chapter 18 of Bjarne Stroustrupp's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++. The question challenges the student to solve it without using any subscripting.

Comment: You should mention the exercise in your question. The exercise contains _"Do not use any standard library functions."_ but you use std::copy.

Comment: Chapter 18 sounds like a good place for it, Ty, down in Algorithms. Mind you, I'm not sure graphics should be covered as early as they are. Good book, but I'd organize it differently. One of the common problems is low-level details like Write Your Own String are often taught in the first few weeks of a C++ course and as a result the course winds up focusing on the details rather than what I see as the important bits: wrangling logic and how to structure a good program. But that could easily be my bias. I fell into programming after I realized a political philosophy degree would starve me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because you are allocating not enough memory for the result string.

```
char* mystrdup(const char* c)
{
    int size = strlength(c);
    char* result = new char;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           
    copy(c, c + size, result);
    return result;      
}
```

Moreover you are not copying the terminating zero to the result string.

At least the two functions `strlength` and `mystrdup` can look the following way

```
size_t strlength( const char *s )
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( s[size] ) ++size;

    return size;
}

char * mystrdup( const char *s )
{
    size_t size = strlength( s ) + 1;

    char *result = new char[size];

    copy( s, s + size, result );

    return result;      
}
```

Of course instead of the standard algorithm `std::copy` you could use the standard C function `strcpy` declared in the header `<cstring>`.

```
strcpy( result, s );
```

And do not forget to delete the allocated array.

```
char* res = mystrdup(test);
//…
delete [] res;
```

Pay attention to that the function `print_array` does not use the variable `size`. There is no need to output a C-string character by character.

The function could be defined like

```
std::ostream & print_array( const char *s, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    return os << s;
}
```

And at last the identifier `c` is usually used with single objects of the type `char`. If you deal with a string then it is better to use the identifier `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple bugs in your code. You allocate wrong memory (char instead of char array). You don't delete the memory. Stop using C-string and use std::string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;

void print_array(const char* c)
{
    while (*c) {
        cout << *c;
        ++c;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string = "Hello!";
    std::string res = test;
    print_array(test.c_str());
    print_array(res.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In strcpy you need to create a char size.

```
char* mystrdup(const char* c)
{
    int size = strlength(c);
    char* result = new char[size];
    copy(c, c + size, result);
    return result;      
}
```